# NSCFTimer supportsContentDimensionVariables crash

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I'm getting an odd crash using a modal UIViewController that is managing a Zbar scanner.

I'm displaying it:

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[self scannerManager] instantiateScannerViewController];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Then dismissing it:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

The crash sometimes is :

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFTimer
>   _supportsContentDimensionVariables]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb2e3b40'

The crash sometimes is:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException',
>   reason: 'Unable to install constraint on view.  Does the constraint
>   reference something from outside the subtree of the view?  That's illegal.

```
>  constraint:<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x15223c60
> h=--- v=--- UIView:0xb4257f0.midX == UITransitionView:0x1521ce50.midX>
> view:<UITransitionView: 0xb4603b0; frame = (0 0; 320 480);
> clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = H; layer = <CALayer: 0xb4602d0>>'
```

In tracking this down, it's definitely related to an auto-layout message I get on the presenting UIViewController:

> All dependent constraints should have been removed from the engine and
>   also from the view's list of dependent constraints

Comment: have you solved the problem? same issue here!

Comment: not exactly. The workaround I found was to hunt down the dependent constraints and remove them. If you can get it to stop complaining about the dependent constraints, it will probably stop crashing. The thing that sucks about that is that I had to radically change the use of auto-layout in the view to achieve this fix.

Comment: also hunting down dependent constraints is not very straightforward. Lots of trial/error.

Comment: In my situation, I had a conflict with a parallel thread. I was detaching it before executing some code. When I switched the two actions it solved my problem.

Comment: I've had the same issue (although supportsContentDimensionVariables was sent to an NSArray - whatever, it's random anyway), but with no complaints about constraints. Turned out it was only happening on the simulator so => ignored for now.